# Django Locale not working after deploying to server [ FIXED ]

Tags: python, django, apache, locale, django-i18n

when i test it locally the translations do worked, but when I deploy it on a server it doesn't work.
Some of the words do get translated but it's not from my locale, it's django's default translation.

In settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
# LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-hans'  # i also tried just putting language code as zh-hans but still ntg gets translated.

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('zh-hans', '简体中文 zh-hans'),
]
```

in urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django_email_verification import urls as mail_urls
from rest_framework.authtoken import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('email/', include(mail_urls)),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    prefix_default_language=False,
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

For the **LOCALE_PATHS** it is correct as i put `print(LOCALE_PATHS)` in the settings and it gave me the right path to my locale "home/username/django_project/locale"

I did do `python manage.py makemessages -l zh_hans` as well as `python manage.py compilemessages`
and restarted my server but still the same.

Btw I'm using AWS ubuntu and apache2. (Not apache problem as i tried `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` before i even installed apache and it's still the same)

My dev comp is windows and my server is ubuntu (not sure how it may help but yea)

and there is no error at all there's just no translation.

what could be the problem ? can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you added `i18n_patterns` to your urls? How are you changing the language?

Comment: yup i did, when i change language it will redirect me to the new url "http://smtg.com/zh-hans/user-dashboard/" i added my urls.py above

Comment: And what is your `LANGUAGES` setting? I've just translated a site into Japanese & all it really needed was `LANGUAGES` and `i18n_patterns`. `LocaleMiddleware` will help do some magic using people's requests, but I don't think that's required.

Comment: yea, it works on development on localhost but not on server so I've no clue why it didn't work, I've added my languages above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely that Django cannot read your translation file correctly.

What is the folder name in your locales folder?
It seems like Ubuntu prefers **capitalized** locale name, such as `zh_Hans` or `zh_HANS`. Try changing the folder name so that Ubuntu can read it correctly.

Please note that when you're changing folder name, you should change it to something else first, because sometimes Ubuntu will think changing from lowercase to uppercase isn't really changing anything. So do an intermediate step like this:

```
cd locales
mv zh_hans/ zh/
mv zh/ zh_Hans/
```

#### Other ways to debug what's the problem

You can also use `django.utils.translation.get_language()` to print out if it's detecting the correct current language code. So if the above line prints out `zh-hans` but you still not see your translation being loaded, it's probably something to do with either locale paths, or the file not being loaded by Django.

You can also log in to admin site and see if the default translation is loaded.

Comment: Omg, thank you very much, I've been trying to fix this for days !!!!

Comment: Changing the name fixed for me if anyone has the same problem this is the solution

Comment: For me, the directory is zh_HANS but it still can not work.
After I run the similar mv command above, and reload the server, it works. Magic!

Answer (score 0):

For me, my translation worked, but 3rd not.

So I have to rename **zh_hans** folder to **zh_Hans** in 3rd-library in `site-packages`.

Because `Linux` is case-sensitive, and Django ignored **zh_hans**